# Can't start asm filter driver

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm

I'm trying to install oracle grid with asm filter driver.

I've already installed grid software only.

As root, I can't start asm. Actually, I don't have any answer from asmcmd filter driver commands:

```
root@srvdb18c:/u01/app/18.0.0/grid/bin# env|grep ORACLE
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/grid
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/18.0.0/grid
root@srvdb18c:/u01/app/18.0.0/grid/bin# ./asmcmd afd_configure
root@srvdb18c:/u01/app/18.0.0/grid/bin#
root@srvdb18c:~# $ORACLE_HOME/bin/asmcmd afd_state
root@srvdb18c:~#
```

What can be the problem?

Important: it's a `Solaris 11` system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configuring Oracle ASM Filter Driver During Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ostmg/administer-filter-driver.html#GUID-6F16B5EC-BE7D-44FA-A05B-A62CF33763D3)

> This procedure must be performed after the Oracle Grid Infrastructure
>   installation zip files have been unzipped in the Oracle Grid
>   Infrastructure home, but before you enable the Configure ASM Filter
>   Driver check box during the installation process when the setup script
>   is run.

```
su root
# set ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/12.2.0/grid
# set ORACLE_BASE=/tmp

# asmcmd afd_label DATA1 /dev/disk1a --init

# asmcmd afd_lslbl /dev/disk1a
```

> Run the setup installation script (gridSetup.sh) to install Oracle
>   Grid Infrastructure and enable Oracle ASM Filter Driver configuration.
>
> On the Create ASM Disk Group wizard page during the installation
>   process, check the Configure ASM Filter Driver box to enable
>   configuration of Oracle ASM Filter Driver and then add your
>   provisioned disks to the initial disk group (typically named DATA).

I used the above before an it worked.

Example: https://balazspapp.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/installing-oracle-12c-release-2-12-2-rac-on-virtualbox-silent-installation-part-3/

Based on the documentation, `afd_configure` and `afd_state` are used when you migrate an existing installation to AFD.